# Shell script to kill custom apps, run another app then restart killed apps?

Tags: shell, scripts

Is it possible to make a shell script that would run using Smanager, for example, to do the following:

1. Kill a list of custom apps loaded from a file
2. Run one custom app loaded from the same file
3. When that app is closed, restore killed apps

If that's not possible, then could it be split into two scripts, one that kills all the custom apps and launch one custom app, the other to restart the custom apps?

All of this is on a rooted phone.
Thanks.

Comment: This is all more than possible on a rooted phone, but before any of us begin writing the script, may I ask why you would want to do this? 

I mean, why go through the trouble of re-loading the killed apps? 

If you're eager to get started on this, Tasker would be the easiest way for you to do it, albeit it'll cost you $8 USD

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I basically want is some sort of "Game Mode", activated before launching a game, desactivated after exiting it. For example, I have some apps bulletproofed (e.g. keyboard, whatsapp, viber, etc) and it would be nice to kill them before launching the game and launch them again  once I'm done.

Comment: That would not be a good idea IMHO - that would be a battery killer - since explicitly killing other apps and services that are not yours, those services and apps will end up getting restarted... and tbqh, killing other apps just for the sake of "Game Mode" is very **bad** idea and if that was published - there'd be uproar about it...

Comment: I wouldn't be killing system services, only user apps such as: viber, whatsapp, SwiftKey, etc.

Comment: Also, gaming isn't exactly battery friendly, and killing some user apps does pay off on lower end devices. In my case, it nullifies the lag while playing PES.

Comment: Gaming has never been battery friendly regardless. And killing apps regardless is not exactly a good way of dealing with it - might be easier to put it another way, switch into airplane mode and run the game, those that are relying on network traffic will quietly shut-up until finished playing the game, and switch off airplane mode, everyone happy!

Comment: Not quite. I'm not trying to avoid distractions, but to gain enough resources to run the game without lagging. Which worked fine for PES, the most demanding game **I**  play on my android. :)

Comment: GermainZ's idea is somewhat legitimate for older devices with less RAM, t0mm13b. However, t0mm13b is right in the sense that the apps would restart themselves as they need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to kill apps when you launch your game. And you are also able to do the opposite, when your game gets closed, Tasker can initialize other apps.

You may use the trial version to test this, but I believe that better results can only be achieved with root.

### Tasker

[Tasker by Crafty Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) available from Google Play Store (4,49€)

From their website you have a [free 14-day trial download](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/download.html).

Comment: Are you affiliated with Tasker? Just curious as you've posted the near identical answer in another question... :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Nop :) I been playing around with it the past few days, and it solves a lot of headaches :D

Comment: @t0mm13b coincidentally, Tasker can be the solution for this past two questions :) But I'll be looking for unanswered questions to promote even more Tasker :D

Comment: yeah, its a dead handy tool alright :) Takes a bit of getting used to their logic which seems counter-intuitive...

Comment: I created a test task (vibrate for 500ms) and it doesn't seem to do anything when I run it (by pressing the play like button)... Not sure if it's a bug or if I got it wrong.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but I believe it's a bug on my side. Will redownload later. Since it does what I'm asking for, I'm accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot&hl=en) will get the job done for you.

Whenever you want to play your game, just launch Fast Reboot and then launch your game. It will free up some extra RAM without interfering with anything critical, and it is much easier than a script.

Don't worry about restarting the apps, because as t0mm said, they will almost immediately restart themselves. (You can launch Fast Reboot twice to see this)

This solution will solve your needs without having to pay for Tasker.

Although, I *do* recommend that app- it can do anything.

Answer (score 0):

In order to start in game mode, I thing you can use the following commands

```
pm enable package_name
```

and

```
pm disable package_name
```

then you should restart some application services like whatsapp in order to restart checking automatically (Not sure if they will automatically restart services since package has been disabled) to do that you can use `am` command, but not sure what where will be the best arguments. You can use the `logcat` command, to debug what intents are being launched.

If you only kill the application it automatically will restart few seconds.

In SManager, at this moment it is not possible execute script after app has finished. But it could be a new feature.

You also should kill SManager in the las line of the script.

```
killall os.tools.scriptmanager
```